# get the Y value of the sectionlist header component

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm creating a spy scroll for a sectionlist and I want to get the Y values of the section list header ,

I tried to use onLayout method but I only get y value of 0 . 
I assume that my component is inside a react-native container so my view gets the relative value of 0 for this container..

this is my code:

```
<Animated.SectionList
                    initialNumToRender={5}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.docRef}
                    sections={data.slice()}
                    renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
                />

renderSectionHeader = ({section}) => {
    const index = section.sort;
    return (
        <View onLayout={e => this.onSectionLayout(e, index)}>
            <SectionListHeader section={section} index={index}/>
        </View>
    )
};

onSectionLayout = ({nativeEvent: {layout: {x, y, width, height}}}, index) => 
{
    console.log(height)
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the Y position relative to the viewport / screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because the SectionHeader is wrapped by a parent view, so the y position is always 0.

an alternative way is ref.measure。like

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.sectionHeaders = []
}

renderSectionHeader = ({section}) => {
    const index = section.sort;
    return (
        <View ref={c => this.sectionHeaders[index] = c}>
            <SectionListHeader section={section} index={index}/>
        </View>
    )
};

componentsDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.sectionHeaders.forEach((ref,index)=>{
        ref.measure((fx,fy,w,h,px,py) => {
           console.log('y pos is ',py))
        })
     })
  }, 500)
}
```

Comment: Do I must add the setTimeout ? do you use it in order to let the sectionlist finish loading?

Comment: @H.Epstein yeah, without the setTimeout, you will get 0 again. i ran a demo and it worked, take a try : )